# Kraken JS middleware and exceptions

Tags: node.js, express, kraken.js

I'm experimenting with KrakenJS, trying to build an basic API to understand things.

One thing I'm unsure of is the middleware, specifically the 404/500 error handling.

```
"fileNotFound": {
    "enabled": true,
    "priority": 130,
    "module": {
            "name":"path:./lib/exceptions/404"
    }
}
```

This catches any 404 errros, and then I handle that myself in my own configuration. However, why is this `fileNotFound` thrown? Where is `serverError` thrown for 500 errors?

I would like to define my own files for other exceptions like a 403, however how would I get this to trigger a middleware?

Comment: I would like to give you an answer but I'm also trying to decipher the workings of Kraken.  I can say, however, that Kraken uses middleware to load the middleware.  That middleware is called "meddleware" just to be clever and confusing.  ;-)  You might get some answers by reading up on it here: https://github.com/krakenjs/meddleware

Answer (score 0):

As @HeadCode mentioned, definitely read up on [meddleware](https://github.com/krakenjs/meddleware) to understand how middleware gets loaded a bit better.

That said, we have to go over a few things in order to make what's happening more clear.

---

#### Handling 404s

First, let's go over how one would typically register a 404 handler in a plain old express app.

Typically you'd have the final middleware in your middleware continuation chain just assume that, if we made it that far without bailing, we simply cannot find the resource. Here's an example:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/firstRoute', function handler(req, res) { res.send('found me'); });
app.get('/secondRoute', function handler(req, res) { res.send('found me');  });

app.use(function notFoundHandler(req, res, next) {
    res.status(404).send('Route Not Found');
});

app.listen(8000, function onListen() { console.log('listening on 8000...'); });
```

Since [routes are resolved in the order they're added in Express 4](https://github.com/strongloop/express/wiki/New-features-in-4.x#no-more-appuseapprouter), as long as your 404 handler is last you can be certain no other route matched.

This pattern is briefly described in the [Express FAQs](http://expressjs.com/starter/faq.html#how-do-you-handle-404s-).

---

#### Handling 500s

Now let's move on to 500s.

Express has the concept of an error-handling middleware (also described on the [Express site](http://expressjs.com/guide/error-handling.html)). An error handling middleware requires an arity of 4 (i.e., takes four arguments) and that's the only difference. They're only executed if an error is signaled which is done by passing an object into your `next` call. Easier explained in code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/firstRoute', function handler(req, res) { res.send('found me'); });
app.get('/secondRoute', function handler(req, res) { throw new Error('oops'); });

app.use(function notFoundHandler(req, res, next) {
    res.status(404).send('Route Not Found');
});

app.use(function errorHandler(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(500).send('Broken. :(');
});

app.listen(8000, function onListen() { console.log('listening on 8000...'); });
```

In the above example, `errorHandler` will only execute if either 1) another middleware or route handler throws an error or 2) we call next with an argument*, .e.g. `next(new Error('oops'))`.

Go ahead and run that. if you visit `/notFound` or any random route, you'll correctly get a 404. If you visit `/firstRoute` you'll get `found me`, and if you go to `secondRoute` you'll get `Broken. :(`.

---

#### What about kraken?

Kraken—or more accurately, [meddleware](https://github.com/krakenjs/meddleware)—just moves defining your middleware into your config. That little block of json you copied above is basically functionally equivalent to the following in a vanilla express app:

```
var fileNotFound = require('./lib/exceptions/404');

// ... app.use() everything with a priority lower than 130 ...
app.use(fileNotFound());
// ... app.use() everything with a priority *greater* than 130 ...
```